# Why is apache giving 503s when using Require ip?

Tags: apache, cloudflare

We recently upgraded from Apache 2.2 to 2.4. We have two web servers that sit behind a load balancer, and these are fed traffic through Cloudflare.

On the web servers we have [mod_cloudflare](https://github.com/cloudflare/mod_cloudflare/blob/master/README.md) installed. We take the load balancers into account with the following directives:

```
CloudflareRemoteIPTrustedProxy 172.21.171.17
CloudflareRemoteIPTrustedProxy 172.21.171.18
```

We have an admin area on multiple sites, as well as some blogs and other scripts that we want to IP restrict. We do this with a regex match in a `Directory` directive like so:

```
<Directory ~ "^/var/www/vhosts/[^/]+/public/((sage_import)|(partner)|((blog/)?wp-)?admin)">
    AllowOverride All
    Require ip 111.111.111.111 222.222.222.222 333.333.333.333
</Directory>
```

Most of the URLs that get processed by this work as expected.

- `domain.tld/sage_import/script.php`
- `domain2.tld/blog/wp-admin`
  etc

However our main admin area, accessed with `domain3.tld/admin` (which worked fine with Apache 2.2) doesn't work. The weird thing is we see a 503 error. No 503 errors show up in the logs - presumably it's not actually hitting a server at all? (I've tailed site specific access and error logs and the general apache access and error log too, with nothing there).

When browsing with ip 111.111.111.111, if I remove that IP from the `Require ip` line, the working pages suddenly show 403 errors as expected and the logs reflect this. The `/admin` page *still* shows the 503 error.

However, when I add the load balancer IPs to the `Require ip` line, the 503 error vanishes and I can now access that page.

```
Require ip 111.111.111.111 222.222.222.222 333.333.333.333 172.21.171.17 172.21.171.18
```

Comparing the logs of the requests after adding the load balancer IP doesn't seem to show anything too interesting:

```
111.111.111.111 (141.101.98.187, 172.21.171.18) - - [27/Nov/2018:21:54:16 +0000] "GET /blog/wp-admin/ HTTP/1.0" 200 77064 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.1 Safari/605.1.15"
...
111.111.111.111 (141.101.98.187, 172.21.171.18) - - [27/Nov/2018:21:54:24 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.0" 200 375 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.1 Safari/605.1.15"
...
111.111.111.111 (141.101.98.187, 172.21.171.18) - - [27/Nov/2018:21:54:37 +0000] "GET /sage_import/export.php HTTP/1.0" 200 33289 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.1 Safari/605.1.15"
```

The LogFormat being used is as follows:

```
LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" combined
```

Note: adding `Require all granted` into the above `Directory` directive also works.

#### Update

I have also tried:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For 111.111.111.111 allow
Require env allow
```

in-place of the `Require ip`, but I still get the same 503 returned,

**What is wrong with my configuration that's causing these 503 errors?**